# Calling a Javascript function within C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pop something based on a condition... but it is not working... and I am kind of a newbie at this so I appreciate the help

```
if (myFileName == OldFileName)
                {
                    btnSubmit.Attributes["OnClick"] = "return confirm('This file already exists, do you want to replace it?');";
                }
```

This is not being call for some reason.. here is the asp code

```
asp:Button class="Button" ID="btnSubmit" CausesValidation="True" Text="SUBMIT" runat="server"
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: From the code in the question, it **looks** like you're trying to _bind_ the JS function, not _call_ it.

Comment: I am newbie.. I am not sure how to go around it

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery? I like to keep javascript out of my code behind pages. Let me know if you would like an example in js or jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx).

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)
[ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx)

Comment: Yes, If the validation is being done on the server-side then you will have to show the alert/confirm after the page posts back to the browser.

Comment: This is too advanced, I will mark it as answered although i am not going to use.. too involved...do not understand it. Thank you though